# Jenkinsfile Step Check if Files Changed in Directory?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am out of my league here so forgive me if this is hard to understand. What I am trying to accomplish is to check if any files have changed in a certain directory during a pull request in my Jenkinsfile setup. If there are files that have changed compared to the `develop` branch, I would like to run the particular stage. This is a declarative pipeline. Let me give you example:

```
stage('Publish Common Module') {
  when {
   // can I check if projects/common/ has any files that are different compared to develop?
   // if so, then I want to run the steps in this stage
  }
}
```

I am not sure if that gives enough background as to what I am trying to accomplish. The reason for this setup is that there are multiple stages that build a module based on if there are changes in the PR for that module.

Apologies if this is not enough information to get an accurate answer.

Comment: You use something like `git diff --name-only develop`

Comment: Awesome. Only question is how do I conditionally check this and if there is a diff, run the command I need to run?

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at [this](https://alexwlchan.net/2017/09/useful-git-commands/) and I think the best way would be to do something like this:

```
stage('Publish Common Module') {
    script{
        if(0 != sh(script: "git diff --exit-code develop", returnStatus: true)){
            // run your stage
        }
    }
}
```

The `exit-code` flags causes git to return something other then 0 when there are changes compared to develop. This exit code is returned (because of `returnStatus`) and compared to 0.

I don't use declarative pipelines, so I don't know if you could also move the condition in a `when` block instead.

Comment: Sorry I have not gotten back to this yet. I am getting an error of unexpected `(` on line 2 that I have not been able to track down yet.